# qt: slot not called guarantee after disconnect of an auto direct connection

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, signals, signals-slots

I have a single-thread gui application and I do not choose a type of connection, so according to documentation the connection will be a direct one. According to documentation then: `"The slot is invoked immediately when the signal is emitted. The slot is executed in the signalling thread."`

For my understanding, this obviously leads to the conclusion that if I disconnect such an auto-connection in a method, then there is a guarantee that there is no possibility that after completion of this method (in which I do the disconnection) I can get a slot (corresponding to the just-disconnected connection) still being called. The reason of that is, as far as I understand, the fact that no event queue is used for such an auto (here direct) connection.

Am I right? Or should I be careful and better keep a `state`-variable and double check this `state` and return from the slot if it's in a some (unclear to me) way still got called? I am especially worried for the situations where I have connections, in which signals are produced by Qt entities (e.g. signals `QNetworkReply::finished()`, etc.), rather than by me, as I do not control them fully.

I have found related questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71091513/qt-slot-still-receives-signals-after-disconnecting), but I have not found the exact question, and so I have inconfidence and decided to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use only direct connections then you can't "receive" any further signals after you disconnected from getting them. Direct connection is just a callback call, nothing more.

Comment: Well, I have a single threaded application so afaiu all my objects are created by the gui thread (the same as the "event thread", if I name things right). So all my auto connections are direct. Am I right? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @JenyaKh yes, you are right. Unless you explicitly create queued connections they all will be direct.